# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Не допускается работать на переносных лестницах ***более одного человека***" - можно ли так сказать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, предложение совершенно кривое. *Работать* - кому? Значит - "одному человеку". А у Вас получилось *работать* - кого? Можно сказать "Не допускается **работа** на переносных лестницах..."

Comment: в силу некоторых обстоятельств изменить таким образом предложение не получится. Надо что-то делать с "более одним человеком"))

Answer (score 0):

На переносной лестнице может находиться только один человек.